# combine two python lists of dict with index

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I want to merge two lists into a nested construct.

List_A: `[{'id':1,'val':'abc'},{'id':2,'val':'bcd'},{'id':3,'val':'efg'}]`
List_B: `[{'ref':1,'name':'xyz'},{'ref':2,'name':'opq'},{'ref:2,'name':'jkl'},{'ref':3,'name':'nmo'}]`

Result should be:

List_C: `[{'id':1,'list_b':[{'name':'xyz'}]},{'id':2,'list_b':[{'name':'opq'},{'name':'jkl'}]},{'id':3,'list_b':[{'name':'nmo'}]}]`

I tried pandas join and merge but got no result. Sure, I could iterate through the list and do it key by key, but there might be a much better solution.

Comment: Do List_A and List_B have to be dictionaries? Based on your example, a list of tuples may be better suited to representing your data, ex List_A ->  `[(1, 'abc'), (2, 'bcd'), (3, 'efg')]` which also hurts the eyes less.

Comment: Data come from a sql read into a pandas dataframe via sqlalchemy, so tuples will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired output, you don't need List_A at all.

```
from collections import defaultdict

b = [{'ref':1,'name':'xyz'}, {'ref':2,'name':'opq'}, {'ref':2,'name':'jkl'},{'ref':3,'name':'nmo'}]
dct = {}
[dct.setdefault(tuple(i), list()).append(j) for *i, j in [tuple(x.values()) for x in b]]
[{'id':k[0], 'list_b':list({'name': n} for n in v)} for k, v in dct.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'list_b': [{'name': 'xyz'}]},
 {'id': 2, 'list_b': [{'name': 'opq'}, {'name': 'jkl'}]},
 {'id': 3, 'list_b': [{'name': 'nmo'}]}]
```

Overall this seems like an over-complicated way to store the data, but if you need that specific format (ex for an input to another program) then w/e.

Comment: List_B might have items which do not match List_A and therefore are ignored. E. g. List_B: [{'ref':1,'name':'xyz'},{'ref':2,'name':'opq'},{'ref:2,'name':'jkl'},{'ref':3,'name':'nmo'},{'ref':4,'name':'rst'}]

Answer (score 0):

```
from copy import deepcopy
List_C = deepcopy(List_A)
for dct1 in List_C:
    dct1.pop('val')
    dct1['list_b'] = list()
    for dct2 in List_B:
        if dct1['id'] == dct2['ref']:
            dct3 = dct2.copy()
            dct3.pop('ref')
            dct1['list_b'].append(dct3)
```

Comment: Thanks Bhagirathi! This is certainly a solution. As I have some 10,000 records to merge, I was just looking for a high performance solution.